# I need to make a 12 sided soccer ball

Tags: modeling

All tutorials I find are for 20 sided balls, based on an Ico spehere. Is there an easy solution to get a 12 sided ball? Thank you!

Comment: A dodecahedron has 12 sides. Is a subdivision surface (simple) and cast modifier acceptable?

Comment: That was the term I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

choose this here:

[image]

then this:

[image]

and you get:

[image]

you need this add-on enabled for this functionality:

[image]